# How to disable animation for ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I am using new [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter), which automatically animates changes. I would like to disable animations or enable/disable it programmatically.

```
class UserAdapter extends ListAdapter<User, UserViewHolder> {
     public UserAdapter() {
         super(User.DIFF_CALLBACK);
     }
     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.bindTo(getItem(position));
     }
     public static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User> DIFF_CALLBACK =
             new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User>() {
         @Override
         public boolean areItemsTheSame(
                 @NonNull User oldUser, @NonNull User newUser) {
             // User properties may have changed if reloaded from the DB, but ID is fixed
             return oldUser.getId() == newUser.getId();
         }
         @Override
         public boolean areContentsTheSame(
                 @NonNull User oldUser, @NonNull User newUser) {
             // NOTE: if you use equals, your object must properly override Object#equals()
             // Incorrectly returning false here will result in too many animations.
             return oldUser.equals(newUser);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Try `android:animateLayoutChanges="false"` on the parent layout?

Comment: I tried (android:animateLayoutChanges="false") on parent layout and on recyclerview, but not working.

Answer (score 47):

Another solution is to simply remove the item animator altogether.

```
recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
```

Comment: and then restore the animation by doing `recyclerView.itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator()`

Comment: what about ViewPager2?

Answer (score 18):

You could try to disable or enable animations with `setSupportsChangeAnimations` on `RecyclerView` item animator:

```
SimpleItemAnimator itemAnimator = (SimpleItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
itemAnimator.setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

Comment: Nice one Aaron!  Did you do this for Espresso tests?

Comment: Hey Matt! No I didn't use this for Espresso tests, it should work fine without turning off change animations here :D

Answer (score 2):

### Solution which bypasses `DiffUtil`

Setting `itemAnimator` to `null` and calling `submitList()` still runs `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` in a background thread and doesn't submit the list on the same frame! If you want the same behaviour as calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, you can do this:

```
adapter.submitList(null)
adapter.submitList(newItems)
```

This is useful if you know the contents are indeed completely different and don't care if you loose the scroll position. Or if you have multiple `RecyclerViews` that all have to update on the same frame (to reduce screen flashing).

### Why does this work?

Looking at the source code of `AsyncListDiffer.submitList()`:

```
// fast simple remove all
if (newList == null) {
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    int countRemoved = mList.size();
    mList = null;
    mReadOnlyList = Collections.emptyList();
    // notify last, after list is updated
    mUpdateCallback.onRemoved(0, countRemoved);
    onCurrentListChanged(previousList, commitCallback);
    return;
}

// fast simple first insert
if (mList == null) {
    mList = newList;
    mReadOnlyList = Collections.unmodifiableList(newList);
    // notify last, after list is updated
    mUpdateCallback.onInserted(0, newList.size());
    onCurrentListChanged(previousList, commitCallback);
    return;
}
```

When you call `submitList()` the first time, all items are immediately removed. The second time they are immediately inserted, never calling `DiffUtil` or starting a background thread computation.

### Putting it all together

```
if(animations) {
    adapter.submitList(newItems)
} else {
    recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
    adapter.submitList(null)
    adapter.submitList(newItems) {
        recyclerView.post {
            //Restore the default item animator
            recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `animations` var? in this line `if(animations) {`

Comment: @DrMido it's a parameter you specify. Set it to true if you want animations, false otherwise. Maybe put the code in a `fun submitData(newItems: List<T>, animations: Boolean)`

Comment: I am not sure IF I understand what you mean correctly, but I used AsyncListDiffer  not diffUtil and the second parameter is on submitList is  @Nullable final Runnable commitCallback) not animation, however when I used  `adapter.submitList(null)` it always moves to the first position of the recycler view, How can I fix that?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, this always scrolls to top ... This is only good for use cases, where the entire dataset changes, not just a few items.